# prove if in connected graph degree of vertices is at most $d$ and there is one vertex of degree $d - 1$, then it can be colored in $d$ colors.

Tags: graph-theory, coloring

Prove that if in the connected graph  degree of each vertex is at most $d$ and there is at least one vertex of degree $d - 1$, then it can be colored correctly in $d$ colors.

I proved that if we need to colour in $d+1$ colours it's possible.
But for $d$ colours I don't know what to do.
I think I have to use induction.

Comment:  no he's not .  thanks